# How do I shrink an EBS volume on Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, amazon-ec2, shrink, disk-volume, amazon-ebs

I have a Windows Server 2008 instance on EC2. I need to shrink one of the drives (non-root) to a certain amount. Is there are well defined way of doing it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a tutorial for Linux boxes described [here](http://blog.edoceo.com/2009/02/amazon-ebs-how-to-grow-storage.html), but while it may not apply directly, the concept is the same.

You'll need to:

1. Create a snapshot of the current EBS volume.
2. Unmount the EBS volume from the host.
3. Create a new volume of the specified size using the previous snapshot from the first step.
4. Remount the EBS volume.

So in essence, you're not resizing anything--you're creating a new EBS volume and transferring the content over using Amazon's built in snapshot system.

Comment: Thanks, but there is one more thing. Current volume is 800GB, now I need only 400GB, and there is 380GB of space which I used up in the 800GB drive. If I by mistake allocate 370 GB (create a volume from the snapshot), will I get an error?, which I should logically thinking. Or should I allocate a new 400GB drive, attach it to the instance, copy the contents from 800GB to 400GB drive and remove the 800GB drive. Is this a good way of doing it?

Comment: The latter would be the safest.

Comment: Didn't help: Volume size 12GiB must be at least snapshot size 30GiB.

Comment: These steps are for increasing the volume size not the other way around! You will get the error: "The size must be at least as big as the snapshot"